# How to implement View Pager inside Recycler View in android in the same class?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented View Pager separately and it's working fine. But how can i put that view pager inside Recycler View. But the problem is my class already extends Recycler view so to implemet View pager inside Recycler view i need to extend the class to FragmentActivity() to work with View Pager. But the class already extends Recycler view. So multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: add view pager as one of the item in recyclerview? also, post some code

Comment: Why you need to do this? Please en-light your question with suitable example

Comment: Could u be more specific? Can u give link to any such implementations?

Comment: Harish Qureshi, I am trying to implement swipe list inside the recycler view

Comment: Multiple views in recylerview, this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type